# Is DotNetZip really using WinZipAes256?

Tags: c#, security, aes, dotnetzip

I'm using dotnetzip for creating some zip files with some AES password
like:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
       zip.Password = PASS;
       zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
       zip.AddFile("test.txt"); 
       zip.Save("test.zip");
 }
```

after this i noticed reading the file without specifying the algorithm that it was working 
with no problem

```
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("test.zip")
 {
       zip.Password = PASS;
       // zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256; 
       foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
       {
           e.Extract(@"C:\tmp\");
       }
 }
```

then there were cases that the extract produced some non readable file but not always; the most times was perfectly readable without specifying the algorithm.

now based on their wiki:

> Create a Zip archive that uses WinZip-compatible AES encryption. Answering concerns that the
>       standard password protection supported by all zip tools is weak, WinZip has extended the ZIP 
>       specification and added a way to use AES Encryption to protect entries in the Zip file.

But don't understand if this is really AES 256 encryption.

Anyway specifying the algorithm it will extract only readable files so the file is for sure readable, now my concern is about the security.

**EDIT**
Be sure you specify the password algorithm before extracting or the files will not always be readable!

Comment: Is there an actual question you would like to ask?

Comment: Yes, maybe is not clear but my actual question is, if the encryption is in aes 256 or pkzip.

Comment: The question _"Does DotNetZip automatically detect the encryption of an archive it is reading when you provide the correct password?"_ is also relevant. You'll have to inspect the zipfile or the code writing the archive in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The zip-entry really does use AES256. In the source code of the dotnetzip library, you can see that the actual encryption algorithm used, is extracted from the byte content itself. That's why you don't need to assign the correct algo while extracting. (just the password)

Source code filling the variable `_Encryption_FromZipFile`: [dotnetzip source](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Zip/ZipEntry.Read.cs)